# (Python 3 OS Win7) List not showing the expected output

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Input URL **http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html**

When I am running this code, the output that is expected is a list containing numbers that is inside the *tag* that is being parsed in the program. But all I am getting is the last number in the list.

**Please correct the program to show the list of numbers present in all the tags that is parsed**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import re

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()

# html.parser is the HTML parser included in the standard Python 3 library.
# information on other HTML parsers is here:
# http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
sum_of_num = 0
tags = soup('tr')
for tag in tags:
    # Look at the parts of a tag
    print('TAG:', tag)
    num = re.findall('[0-9]+',str(tag))
print(num)
```

Comment: You can select by span.comments , ie: `soup.select('span.comments')`. Then get text, turn to int and sum.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a list, you must build a list. You need to declare the empty list first, then append the values in each iteration :

```
res = []
for tag in tags:
    # Look at the parts of a tag
    print('TAG:', tag)
    res.append(re.findall('[0-9]+',str(tag)))

print(res)
```

if you need a pretty readable output, you can use `pprint`

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(res)
```

(by printing `num` at the end, outside the loop, you only print the last value calculated, escaping from the loop)